# How to increase scanning the area before sharing the anchor to the cloud

Tags: unity-game-engine, azure-spatial-anchors

How can I increase the capturing the environment before sharing the anchor to the cloud? At the moment I'm able to capture only upto hundred percent but I want to scan the area upto 10 times of the current value.

```cs
public bool EnoughDataToCreate => this.GetSessionStatusIndicator(SessionStatusIndicatorType.RecommendedForCreate) >= 2;
```

I have increased by 2% but unable to increase more than this.

Answer (score 0):

Today is not possible to change the amount of data that is collected for an anchor. The **readyForCreateProgress** and **recommendedForCreateProgress** are there to provide feedback when you gather the recommended or enough amount of data to create the anchor. The value is a float that can go up to 2 for 200%.

When scanning an area, you can improve the quality of the data by ensuring that by the time you reach 200%, you have scanned all areas of the environment from which you may want to be able to recall your anchors.

Another option to consider is to create multiple anchors within the same session; as long as they are created within the same session, recalling any of these anchors will allow you to then call our "nearby" API to find all anchors you placed in that environment.

We are continually looking for feedback and you can submit it here: https://feedback.azure.com/forums/919252-azure-spatial-anchors

Comment: I tried the exact same thing. Increased it to 200% and yet, anchors don't really localize easily. Perhaps, one in ten attempts. Is there anything I can do to make it better?

Comment: Ignore my previous comment. It works perfectly fine on ARCore SDK v1.5. Refer [this](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/919252-azure-spatial-anchors/suggestions/37359406-support-to-arcore-sceneform-1-8-0).